Auth0 Logout Not Fully Logging Out – Auto Login Without Password Prompt
I am using Auth0 for user authentication in a React application. The login flow works perfectly fine. However, I'm encountering issue with the logout flow. When a user logs out of my application using the logout function provided by Auth0, they are redirected to the homepage as expected. However, when they try to log in again, they are automatically logged back in without begin prompted for their credentials.
const logoutUser = async () => {

    logout({
      returnTo: window.location.origin,
      federated: true,
    });

    try {
      await axios.get(`https://${import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_DOMAIN}/v2/logout`, {
        params: {
          client_id: `${import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}`, 
          returnTo: window.location.origin, 
          federated: true, 
        },
        withCredentials: true, 
      });
  
      document.cookie.split(";").forEach((cookie) => {
        const name = cookie.split("=")[0].trim();
        document.cookie = `${name}=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/`;
      });
  
      window.location.href = window.location.origin;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during logout:", error);
    }
    
  };

This is the function I am calling when the user clicks on Logout button
I have tried all solutions I found, making a call to the https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/v2/logout URL, manually clearing the cookies, calling the logout function of Auth0. But nothing is working.
This is my Auth0 Dashboard
I want the log out process to completely log out users out of the application and when the user tries to log back in, they should be prompted to enter their credentials again.

Note that for JWT authentication, you need to explicitly logout in the frontend as well. Only loggin g out in the backend (calling  the /v2/logout endpoint) will just prevent the backend from renewing your JWT. The JWT already stored in the frontend is still valid since it's self contained, and must be deleted aswell.
Could it be that you did not call the logout function in the frontend? It will delete the local JWT for you.
I always found the React Auth0 library a bit poorly documented, and tend to look at the plain JS documentation to figure out how to use the React SDK. Check out the logout function from the Auth0ContextInterface
Here are some general guidance:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/interactive#add-logout-to-your-application
